# Insert contents of file into all text files after the string "pattern"

Tags: linux

The command

```
sed -i '/pattern/r file.ttt'  file1.txt
```

Add all test in the file.txt after the string here into the file1.txt. But I'm not able to do the same for all files txt

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '/pattern/r file.ttt/g'  {} \;
```

Comment: Are you able to list the files need from the `find /path/to/search -name '*.txt'` command? You are missing specifying the path to search for

Comment: What is the purpose of `/g` in the second command? If you remove it, is should work.